# How long does it take for the Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS initial boot?

Tags: usb-installation

Once I got the boot sequence and boot type corrected in BIOS and Ubuntu started booting, all my computer says is "Booting..." It has been like this for over 30 minutes. Is this normal?  Thanks.

Comment: Normal boot times for me would be 45 seconds for a hard drive and 15 seconds for an SSD.

Comment: "How long does it take for the Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS initial boot?" depends on your hardware. "It has been like this for over 30 minutes. Is this normal?" No. Even on relative old hardware 2 minutes is a lot; boot times should be a little bit quicker than Windows boot time (if you have experience booting Windows that is). What kind of answer did you expect? If you do not investigate this and show us logs or error notices or something similar we got nothing to go on ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please notice my name "KindlyRetarded". It's like that for a reason. The first option in the boot menu was to boot from hard drive. This is the default option so when the timer timed out and started the boot sequence there was nothing there to boot from as I had not installed the OS yet. I powered down the computer and started it up again. This time I chose the second option which allowed me to move through and install Ubuntu. No more problems.